# abusive teacher failing my life partner

Tags: graduate-school, professorship

this teacher has done the following in a required, non-elective class:

- forced students to provide personal reflections in their health, including those with trauma for whom that is triggering
- responded critically to said personal reflections, sometimes in mocking tone, sometimes in all caps
- provided contradictory and confusing instructions
- refused to respond to requests for clarification for said instructions
- failed assignments submitted by students who picked the wrong interpretation of said confusing instructions
- failed assignments for picking the wrong subset of a list of ten options when instructions indicated they could pick any of the above options.
- refuses to meet with students to discuss any of the above issues

the students in this class have already sought assistance from their advisors, who directed them to the vice dean, from the vice dean, who revealed their identities and complaints to the abusive professor, and to the dean, who instructed them to contact the disability office about trauma, or to tough it out. The disability office has not returned complainants phone calls.

The affected students have begun building up a paper trail, and are discussing contacting the accrediting institution for the university.

Has anyone experienced anything of this magnitude? Did you contact the accreditors? What did they do? What other recourse do this teacher’s victims have?

Comment: Don’t walk. Run.

Comment: Maus, questions asking about other people's experiences with similar situations are usually closed here.  Since you mention accreditation, I guess you are asking about the United States.  Accreditation agencies in the United States do not handle student complaints.  The students involved should follow the University's complaints procedure exactly.  If that is unsuccessful, litigation is your remaining option.  I am not a lawyer, but this sounds like a law suite the University would loose in the United States.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put **all** the evidence together with supporting statements (calendar, who contacted, responses including emails etc) and send to the Governing board as well as the accrediting institution.

However, this may get you back more attention than you wish so make sure it is what you all want.

But, I don't think the teacher should be allowed to continue and the behavior of the vice & dean may be called into question...